# CSS: div height not filling vertically

Tags: css, html, height, fill

I have a div (in the attached example, `.report`) which I would like divided into two divs (`.report-title` and `.sections`). **Both divs should fill the container div vertically, and I'm struggling to make this happen consistently**. I don't want to stretch the container vertically; I want `.report` to only be tall enough to contain the content, and for both of the contained divs to have an equal height. Neither div should have a set height or function as a table. The goal is to have the divs be responsively sized, except with `.report`, `.report-title`, and `.section`s equally tall; they should all have the same height as whichever is taller at the moment.

What is currently happening looks something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

What I'd like to happen would look something like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

I've tried setting heights to 100% and attempting some jQuery tricks, so far with no luck. What is the simplest solution here?

**HTML:**

```
<div class='report'>
    <span class='report-title'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lobortis elit non dui convallis, ut ornare est semper. Mauris eget libero vitae mi varius lobortis.
    </span>
    <span class='sections'>
        <span class='report-section'>Date: 2013-05-07</span>
        <span class='report-section'>Number: ABC123</span>
        <span class='report-section'>Themes:
            Chrome, Web Design, jQuery
        </span>
        <span class='report-section'>Sentiment: Positive</span>
        <span class='report-section'>
            URL: 
            <a href='http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector'>
                http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector
            </a>
        </span> <!-- report-section -->
    </span> <!-- sections -->
</div> <!-- report -->
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.report {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
}

.report-section {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.report-title {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 125%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: bold;
    width: 38%;
}

.sections {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 59%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/

Comment: your post is not clear!!! what are you expecting?

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed, I am trying to get the .report-title and .sections divs to both fill the .report div vertically. I will bold that section of my question to make it clearer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, the fiddle has been updated accordingly. The key issue still remains.

Comment: What issue? http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/4/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The `.report-title` div still does not fill the `.report` div vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/22/)

```
html , body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.report {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.report-section {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

.report-title {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left:2px;
    font-size: 125%;
    text-decoration: bold;
    min-width: 50%
}

.sections {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

You set `padding-right:10px` to the right div which pushed it down even if it was floated because the total width exeeded the space.

---

Without using `display:table;` and `display:table-cell` :

### Updated: [Click to see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/20/)

Comment: In your version, the `.report` is taller than it needs to be, creating white space on the botttom. I don't want to stretch the container vertically; I want `.report` to only be tall enough to contain the content, and for of the contained divs to have an equal height.

Comment: ok i will fix it.But they are seperated horizontally now as you wanted.Right?

Comment: I do want them beside each other instead of on top each other, yes. In the long run, I would like them to fill the horizontal space fully; in the version you linked, there is a gap.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson I have updated my fiddle.I will change my css posted in answer if its correct.

Comment: the fiddle linked in your answer still has extra white space on the bottom of all three divs. I've updated my question to try and make this point clearer.

Comment: This is working as I requested, however, the individual `.report-section`s no longer flow smoothly into the `.sections` div. Neither div should have a set or function as a table. The goal is to have the divs be responsively sized, except with `.report-title` and `.sections` equally tall; they should both have the same height as whichever is taller at the moment.

Comment: I can't figure out how to create it; that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: In my version, the individual `.report-sections` flowed smoothly into the `.sections` div like text, with a variable amount on each line. This also meant the height of the `.sections` div was variable depending on the content. I want to keep that responsive size and distribution; I just want the opposing div to respond accordingly to fill up the `.report` div.

Comment: Can you add an image of what you commented above because i dont think i can help you without having a clue

Comment: I've updated the images to try and be more clear; I don't want the individual `.report-section`s to display like block elements, but rather as inline elements. They should only be as wide as the content requires, and there should be the potential for multiple `.report-section`s on the same line if there is enough space.

Comment: Ok i made it .I will add it in 5 min

Comment: Ah, very clever! This is very close, however, for me, there is still an extra bit of space below the `.sections` div.

Comment: I've removed the padding on those two elements, but the extra space below `.sections` seems to remain: http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/18/

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson i have updated my fiddle and now its displaying correctly

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not behaving correctly: if you add more text to the `.report-title` div, the `.sections div does not expand vertically as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/21/

Comment: Its best to use a table structure for such layouts.See my first fiddle.I dont think there is any better solution

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson Check my first fiddle that i updated.I think table structure is the only possible solution for this from what i know.

Answer (score 0):

Apply float:left; and reduce width:36%; for .report-title

Comment: While this works with certain screen widths, whenever the `.sections` div is taller than the `.report-title` div, the problem reoccurs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as follow:

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/dkeWs/9/)

```
html , body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.report {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.report-section {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.report-title {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 125%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: bold;
    width: 38%;
}

.sections {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 59%;
}
```

Comment: In your version, the divs are above eachother; I'd like them to remain beside eachother. I've added some basic graphics to try and make my question clearer.

Comment: In your version, the .report is taller than it needs to be, creating white space on the botttom. I don't want to stretch the container vertically; I want .report to only be tall enough to contain the content, and for both of the contained divs to have an equal height. I've updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson its showing perfect for me. which browser you testing?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows. The `.report-title` and the `.sections` div are both much taller than they need to be to contain their content.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can get from your explanation is this what you mean?
http://jsfiddle.net/dkeWs/10/

I have changed a few CSS options just as adding `float: left;` and `float: right;`

Comment: In your version, the .report is taller than it needs to be, creating white space on the botttom. I don't want to stretch the container vertically; I want .report to only be tall enough to contain the content, and for both of the contained divs to have an equal height. I've updated my question and fiddle to make this clearer.